# Insert data into a column of table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table with 2 columns: `SolarDate` , `GregorianDate`

And I have a function for convert Gregorian date to solar date in T-SQL. When a row is inserted into this table, it only make fill `GregorianDate` column.

I want when a row is inserted, `SolarDate` field is filled too.

Do I need to a trigger? Or another things?

And how can I do this?

Comment: Show the code of how you fill the one date and we can then possibly help.

Comment: You could use a trigger - or just define your `SolarDate` as a **computed column** based on that function that you have

Answer (score 7):

You could use a trigger - or just define your `SolarDate` as a **computed column** based on that function that you have.

In that case - you need to first remove that column `SolarDate` that you already have, and then add it again as a **computed column**:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD SolarDate AS dbo.DetermineSolarDate(GregorianDate)
```

This would constantly and automatically determine the `SolarDate` whenever you need that value, and you don't need to have a trigger in place for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed column on your table that uses your UDF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ArbSQ
(
    @Num1 INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN POWER(@Num1, 2)

END
GO

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyNum INT
    ,MySQ AS dbo.ArbSQ(MyNum) 
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

In this example (no longer using the scalar UDF), the computed column can be [PERSISTED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx);

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyNum INT
    ,MySQ AS POWER(MyNum, 2) PERSISTED
)

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```